# Why am I unable to access the network shares on my own computer?

Tags: windows-7

I am having some problems with media center computer, with Windows 7 on it.

The computers IP address is `192.168.1.13`, and another computer can without any problem navigate to `\\192.168.1.13`, but the computer itself can not. Neither `\\servername` nor `\\localhost`.

If I reboot the computer a couple of times, it will work again, but this is a big problem as my computer cleans my media center library on boot and there, if it can not access `\\192.168.1.13`, it will think that all the files have been removed and therefore delete them from the database.

I really have no idea on where to start with this problem, but if anyone has tried this before and fixed it, I would be very happy, as it would save me from having to reinstall the whole system.

Comment: A computer should not attempt to access itself from a local lan ip address `localhost` is a much better solution for that.  In most home networking situations you are not able to "ping" yourself.  Depending on the exact configuration you can ping other members on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the computer itself can not

Man, I faced that problem some times. Go to folder properties, see "Security" and "Sharing" tabs and check if current user on your own computer is allowed to access that sharing (on Sharing tab) and to access the files inside that (on Security tab).

If you are using that sharing solution at home or on a security place, or only for test purposes, you can add the user "all" and grant all permissions to it on Sharing tab to check if you can access shared folder, and the same for Security tab to check if you can access the files inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the issue related to same software that block connection eg firewall (maybe window 7 default firewall.

You may also try some sniffer tools to get actual information what happens on the network with your requests.